# Azure policy cannot capture routeTables by specifying subnet name

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I need a policy to restrict routes of a routeTable which is associated to a specific subnet.

But, I cannot capture any routeTable by specifying subnet's name:

```json
"policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/subnets[*].name",
            "like": "*"
          }
        ]
      },
```

However, I can get routeTables by specifying subnet id:

```json
"policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/subnets[*].id",
            "like": "*"
          }
        ]
      },
```

How should I write the policy so I can restrict(audit) the routes of a routeTable which is associated to a specific subnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "Get-AzRouteTable" to get Microsoft.Network/routeTables/subnets[*]
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-azroutetable?view=azps-6.0.0

The Microsoft.Network/routeTables/subnets[*].id would look like this:
/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/XXX/subnets/XXX

Comment: Thank you. I found it seems there is no `subnets[*].name` property. I don't understand why document states the field `Microsoft.Network/routeTables/subnets[*].name` is valid..